# Solve problem 'connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER'

Tags: c#, oracle

I try to connect to  oracle sys user by c# code and give me this error

```
ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
```

my connection code

```
 OracleConnection financonn3 = new OracleConnection(connectionString: @"DATA SOURCE=10.10.10.150/bills;PASSWORD=xxxxxxx;USER ID=sys;");
```

what the way to solve this problem

Comment: you might create an ordinary user instead of using `sys` which's critically important and should only be used for administrational purposes.

Answer (score 6):

The error caused because you want to use `sys` user but didn't set `DBA Privilege=SYSDBA` in your connection string.

default `DBA Privilege` will be a normal user.

```
OracleConnection financonn3 = new OracleConnection(connectionString: @"DATA SOURCE=10.10.10.150/bills;DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;PASSWORD=xxxxxxx;USER ID=sys;");
```

**Note**

I would suggest you use other create user instead of `sys` to be your using user.
because `sys` is a very important role in oracle like an administration.

Comment: I agree about creating a non-SYS user account. It's hard to think of anything one would do through C# that requires a SYSDBA account (unless building a database admin application).